# Install Firefox 57 on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, software-installation, firefox, gtk3, gtk2

I did the following steps to install Firefox 57 on CentOS 6.5 :

1) `wget http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/57.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-57.0.tar.bz2`

2) `tar xvjf firefox-57.0.tar.bz2`

3) `sudo ln -s /usr/local/firefox/firefox /usr/bin/firefox`

4) `firefox`

I get the following Error:

```
libgtk-3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Is it possible to install Firefox 57 on CENTOS 6.5 ?

Comment: check the [Firefox 57.0.4 System Requirements](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/57.0.4/system-requirements/)

Answer (score 1):

To handle this kind of error in general, you need to search the database for the missing file. To begin with, you need to update the database by

```
sudo yum makecache
```

After that you can search for the target file

```
yum provides "*/libgtk-3.so.0"
```

You will find that you need a package named `gtk3`, now install it

```
sudo yum install gtk3
```

Now you should have the `libgtk-3.so.0` file located in `/usr/lib64`.

There are rare cases that a shared object file is not installed to the default location and you need to manually tell the system where to find it. You can achieve this by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Although in this case, this step is completely unnecessary because `/usr/lib64` is one of the default locations to search for shared object files.

Comment: But It is mentioned here ( https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=50463) that it is not possible to install gtk3 on CentOS 6.5.

Comment: The thread does not explain why it is impossible, and yes I admit that I am using CentOS 7. If the above method really doesn't work for you. You can either add custom repo, download rpm from rpm-hosting sites and manually installing them, or compile from source.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Could you please update the answer with the above mentioned approch.. it's reallly helpful.

Comment: I cannot be sure about the detailed procedures until I can try that out myself. But you can follow the general procedure of adding ppa repositories or compiling from source tarballs.

Comment: to ignore flatpak and snap in the search use `locate libgtk-3.so.0|egrep -v 'flatpak|snap'|grep -e 'so.0$'
`

Comment: This worked: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./firefox-portable` (installed with this script: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/b999c1bc6d10ab802536 )